# Parse server CLP

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I'm trying to get the CLP to work but for some reasons it does not. I had it to work before and I can't find how again.

I have a profile class which contains a pointer field to a user. I set the CLP as follow :

[image]

I also hooked a beforeFind on Profile and logged the request to make sure the user does get sent, and it does.

Last part of request sent :

```
user: ParseUser { _objCount: 20, className: '_User', id: 'a8tThkoh3j' },
  installationId: '00cb69b7-d74c-49fd-8546-e824c0c49097'
}
```

However, I still get :

```
error: Parse error: Permission denied for action find on class profile. {"code":119,"stack":"Error: Permission denied for action find on class profile.\n    at Function.validatePermission (C:\\Users\\JP\\
Desktop\\Projets\\auction\\back\\node_modules\\parse-server\\lib\\Controllers\\SchemaController.js:1422:11)\n    at SchemaController.validatePermission (C:\\Users\\JP\\Desktop\\Projets\\auction\\back\\nod
e_modules\\parse-server\\lib\\Controllers\\SchemaController.js:1427:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\JP\\Desktop\\Projets\\auction\\back\\node_modules\\parse-server\\lib\\Controllers\\DatabaseController.js:1111:65\
n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add read permission for authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

Philippe,

The reason is a bug in the last published version of parse dashboard (2.1.0). Take a look at this [pull request](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard/pull/1556) for additional information.

The possible workarounds are to downgrade to the previous version of the parse dashboard 2.0.4 or to work with parse dashboard master (the pull request above is already merged into master).

Regards
Valdes